# On Monterey, where are the downloaded wallpapers saved?

Tags: monterey

I am on the new Monterey macOS, and it appears in `System Preferences` that you have to *download* some wallpapers, such as the wallpaper for Big Sur, Catalina, etc. When I download it, where exactly is it stored?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The downloaded wallpapers are stored in `/System/Library/AssetsV2/com_apple_MobileAsset_DesktopPicture`, and after poking around it seems that some of these wallpapers (`HEIC` format) are around `100 MB` in size, at least for the dynamic wallpapers.

Edit: for static wallpapers, you might look at `/Users/[yourname]/Library/Application Support/com.apple.mobileAssetDesktop/`. You will also see the dynamic wallpapers. If you want to remove these wallpapers, just right click on one in System Preferences, then click remove download when it is not your active wallpaper.

Comment: Are you sure? I just checked my machine and that folder did not exist. I'm also trying to find where these are downloaded...

Comment: Nevermind, I found it. Your path was slightly wrong. It’s /System/Library/AssetsV2/com_apple_MobileAsset_DesktopPicture. You were missing the “AssetsV2” folder.

Answer (score 4):

The wallpaper is not in system on my machine, it is found in:

```
/Users/[Your Username]/Library/Application Support/com.apple.mobileAssetDesktop
```

Answer (score 1):

On my Mac, which has an OS version of Monterey 12.2.1, the Desktop Pictures folder is at `/System/Library/Desktop Pictures/`

**Finder** > **Go** > **Go to Folder** > `/System/Library/Desktop Pictures/`

Comment: Not sure why the downvotes... I'm on Monterey 12.6.3, and this is where a lot of these images are: `/System/Library/Desktop Pictures/` The `.madesktop` files are just XMLs describing the image. The `.heic` files are the images.